# How to reference JavaScript code in MasterPage from within another aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharedpreferences, master-pages

Simple question: How do I refer to JavaScript code on a Master page file, (which is also on the **same folder** as many other ASPX pages), from one of my ASPX pages?

**Master Page**

```
    <%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="JobRegister.master.cs" Inherits="JobRegister_Job" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Tec-NQ miJob Register</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        textarea { font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt; }
        a { white-space: nowrap; }
        .tablestyle { background-color:#eeeeee; width:100%; margin-bottom:2px; padding:3px; }
        .checkboxlist input { position:relative; left: 360px; }
        .checkboxlist label { position:relative; left: -22px; }
        .hidepanel { display: none; }
        .showpanel { display: block; }
        </style>

        <script src="<%# ResolveUrl("~/") %>" type="text/javascript">
            /*
                Added : Variables required for image uploading & validation checking.
                By : Amit Champaneri
                On : 4th April 2008
            */
            var hoverColor = "#00000b"; //DIV Color when mouse is hover the DIV
            var defaultColor = "black"; //DIV default color
            var selectColor = "#000000"; // DIV color when its selected.
            var selectedDIV = "";        //ID of the DIV user has currently selected(it will be 1,2,3 or 4)                
            var objActiveX; //Object of Clipboard ActiveX control.
..
..etc..
```

My ASPX page has a reference to the Javascripts in the Master Page ...

**ASPX page**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/JobRegister/JobRegister.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Details.aspx.cs" Inherits="JobRegister_Details" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="tecnq" TagName="JobAction" Src="ActionControl.ascx" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="JobID, CreatedBy" GridLines="None" 
        AllowPaging="True" DefaultMode="Edit" OnDataBound="FormView1_OnDataBound" OnItemCreated="FormView1_OnItemCreated"
        OnItemUpdated="FormView1_OnItemUpdated" OnItemUpdating="FormView1_Updating"
        HeaderText="Job Details" CellPadding="0" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="10pt">
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Center" Height="30px" />
        <InsertItemTemplate>
...
..etc..
...
<img id="imgPaste1" src="Images/imgPaste.gif" class="LinkImage" title="Click here to Paste any copied Image" onclick="javascript:pasteOnClick('1');" />
..
..etc..
..
```

I got all this from a great blog on how to paste clipboard IMAGEs into a web form ...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25967/Clipboard-ActiveX-for-Image-Copy-Paste-into-Web-Fo

The demo in the above blog works great, but both the Javascript and the ASPX code are all inside the same file!

How can I do the same with the Javascript in the MasterPage and have references to the scripts in my ASPx file?

I tried also to place all the code inside just my ASPX file but I get an invalid reference error on this line of code ...

```
document.getElementById("<%=hdnImageFileName1.ClientID %>").value = "";
```

It's saying it cannot find a reference to "hdnImageFileName1", but I know it's in my ASPX page further down ...

ie

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnImageFileName1" />
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which file `hdnImageFileName1` is present?

Comment: Just updated my question with that answer Rahul. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean paste in web form? ActiveX is an almost outdated technology!!!

Comment: Embedding code in a script tag that points to a js resource doesn't make sense...You can view this in JS console to see for yourself. http://plnkr.co/edit/gDDGZpiSCzC3BGylqbre?p=preview

Comment: @deostroll. Thanks. So how should I go about it, to have all the JS code in the masterfile and references to the code in my ASPX file, both of which are on the same folder? Or is the problem that I am placing the JS code incorrectly?

Comment: It seems you have to design your javascript to be generic. It should have some api which takes your desired control and "process". If it is generic enough on these lines you can keep it anywhere...provided its properly referenced to from the web page.

Comment: @deostroll Sorry, but I am a JS noob. How do you make JS "generic"?

Comment: @Fernando68 Start by moving all your js to another file...reference that file in markup...see how that works for you...you might have to make changes in your code...eventually hoping you would figure it out...revert if necessary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was like @deostroll said. I moved all my JS code into a custom.js file and referenced it simply via markup. Simple. Done! Thank you